# Draw Function Graphc based on LaTeX code of function

Tags: latex

I am writing a paper with LaTeX and there is a conclusion:

```
H' = h - \sum_{i=1}^{h-1}[1-(1-p)^i]^m
```

But I want to show the figure of H' based on different p and m (assume h=4).
I try to draw the figure with Grapher on Mac OS X, but I think I can't just copy the LaTeX code into Grapher. Can anyone suggest a software which can draw the figure of H base on the LaTeX code?

Comment: This function is not really complex, why not manually translate it into the Grapher syntax?

Comment: In fact, this is one of the conclusions, I have about 10 equations, some of which are much more complicated than this one.